# How do I get the individual numbers from my fibonacci sequence to be listed?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

This is what I was tasked to do:

The Fibonacci series (0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21, …) begins with 0 and 1 and has the property that each subsequent Fibonacci number is the sum of the previous two Fibonacci numbers.

Your task is to translate the series into a program, using recursion, that will calculate the Fibonacci value up to the input integer.

How do I get the individual digits and list it in the way shown in picture 2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int target, int num1, int num2);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Know the Fibonacci Sequence up to the nth 
term." ;
cout << '\n';
cout << "Input n: ";
cin  >>  n;
cout << "The sequence up to fibonacci(" << n <<"):";
cout << '\n';
cout << fibonacci(n-1,0,1);
cout << '\n';


return 0;
}

int fibonacci(int target, int num1, int num2)
{


cout << num1 << " ";
if(target == 0)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
else {
    fibonacci(target-1, num2, num1 + num2);
}

}
```

This is how my program runs for now
[image]

This is my goal

[image]

Comment: please include text as text in the question. No imgages please

Comment: You forgot to return the value from the recursion, which leads to undefined behaviour when you try to use it later.

Comment: On an unrelated note, digits and numbers are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you arrive to `n = 0`, you return the next Fibonacci number, because of your addition :

```cpp
if(target == 0)
{
    // here you have:
    // num1 = 34
    // num2 = 55
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

To fix it, juste return `num2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have closely observed your output, the last Fibonacci number printed by your program is `89` which is the `12`<sup>th</sup> number of Fibonacci series and not the `11`<sup>th</sup>. In fact your program is printing `1` extra Fibonacci number then the what user is requested to print. As you can see, you have entered `10` as input and your program is printing `11` Fibonacci numbers starting from `0` (in which the last one is not in sequence).

Since, you just want to print the series, you don't need to return any thing from your `fibonacci()` function because you are printing the Fibonacci series numbers in the recursive calls as you are calculating them.

If you want to print the Fibonacci series numbers with sequence numbers (as you have shown in picture 2), modify `fibonacci()` function signature and add one more parameter which will be the sequence number of the current Fibonacci series number to be printed. Check this:

```
#include <iostream>

void fibonacci(int seqNum, int target, int num1, int num2);

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "Know the Fibonacci Sequence up to the nth term." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input n: ";
    std::cin  >>  n;
    std::cout << "The sequence up to fibonacci(" << n <<"):" << std::endl;
    fibonacci(0, n, 0, 1);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void fibonacci(int seqNum, int target, int num1, int num2) {
    if (target <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    std::cout << seqNum << ".\t" << num1 << std::endl;
    fibonacci(seqNum + 1, target - 1, num2, num1 + num2);
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Know the Fibonacci Sequence up to the nth term.
Input n: 11
The sequence up to fibonacci(11):
0.  0
1.  1
2.  1
3.  2
4.  3
5.  5
6.  8
7.  13
8.  21
9.  34
10. 55
```

The above program is just to show you a way to get output in the format you want. Note that, you need to take care invalid user input because if user give input greater than or equal to `48`, it will result in overflow on a platform where the integer size is `4` bytes (as you have declared  `num1` and `num2` as `signed int` type). I am leaving it up to you to take care of validity of user input. Also, if you want to print only positive Fibonacci numbers, it make sense to declared `num1` and `num2` as `unsigned` type rather than a `signed` type.